# Question about template literal parameters

Tags: javascript

```js
function getPersonInfo(one, two, three) {
  console.log(one);
  console.log(two);
  console.log(three);
}

const person = "d";
const age = 10;
getPersonInfo`${person} is ${age} years old`;
```

Why is the `one` array `[ '', ' is ', ' years old' ]`?

`'is'` and `'years old'` can also be divided into smaller arrays, what is the principle?

Comment: @MichaelM. This is a valid JavaScript called [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)

Comment: @ThumChoonTat My bad, didn't even know that existed :) Thanks for the knowlege!

Comment: What's the result that you wanna get? "d is 10 years old"?

Answer (score 2):

If a tagged template string is used, the value of the first parameter is always an array of string values. The remaining parameters get the value of the expression passed to the template string!

Here are the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)